# VB.NET - Overwrite field in Acess Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

In my game I need to save the score after the user has logged in. The user who has logged in has their name displayed in a textbox on the form. I am having trouble overwriting the score field specific to the user.

My current code that saves the score and level to a new row and not the user who is logged in:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_User ([Score], [Level])VALUES(@Score, @Level) WHERE User='" & txtUser.Text & "'"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", lblScore.Text)     'Adds score to table
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", lblLevel.Text)     'Adds level to table
```

Thanks

Comment: use UPDATE..SET instead of INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to overwrite you need to use UPDATE command and not INSERT, like:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_User SET [Score]=@Score, [Level] = @Level WHERE User=@User"
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", lblScore.Text)     'Adds score to table
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", lblLevel.Text)     'Adds level to table
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", txtUser.Text)     'Adds user to table
```

Comment: There is still a problem here. USER is a reserved keyword.